# interface cannot be cast (ClassCastException: AlarmReceiver cannot be cast to AlarmReceiver$OnAlarmOver)

Tags: java, android

I created a alarm and I hope when alarm is stop can set a String to TextView in MainActivity so I try to use interface but it's get error :

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: AlarmReceiver cannot be cast to AlarmReceiver$OnAlarmOver

AlarmReceiver.java

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  public AlarmReceiver() {
  }

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    ...

    OnAlarmOver onAlarmOver = (OnAlarmOver) context; //<--error
    onAlarmOver.OnAlarmOverText("Alarm stop");        
  }

  public interface OnAlarmOver {
    public void OnAlarmOverText(String overText);
  }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AlarmReceiver.OnAlarmOver {

  ...

  public void OnAlarmOverText(String overText){
    alarm_text.setText(overText);
  }
}
```

My English is very poor, sorry.

Comment: Could you please print `context.getClass().getName()` to the logcat (or to a toast) at the point of the error, and tell us what the result is?

Comment: Toast result is android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext

Comment: So, in that case, your context isn't your main activity, since the alarm can get triggered while your main activity is closed. Alarms are designed for slightly different purposes than timers.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cast the context to OnAlarmOver. Of course, this is not going to work. I think you want to capture a broadcast emit somewhere else inside of your app.

1) You need to define your broadcast. Then, in your activity, you should register it. For example:

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            if(intent.getAction().equals(SearchService.NOTIFICATION)){

            }
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(SearchService.NOTIFICATION));
}
```

Remember to unregister in the pause method

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}
```

2) You need to create an Intent and the send the broadcast like this.

```
private void publishResults(Search result) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(NOTIFICATION);
    intent.putExtra(RESULT, result);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
    success = true;
}
```

To sum up, I don't know why you want to use an interface (listener) for this if it is is provided by Android. Maybe, you should explain a little more what do you want to do. I hope this answer can help you.